# Show an element in the group of unit of S has infinite order

Tags: abstract-algebra

$$ S=\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&c\end{pmatrix}:a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z} \Bigg\}$$

By applying the definition of unit
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_0&0\\b_0&c_0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1&0\\b_1&c_1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&0\\b_1&c_1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_0&0\\b_0&c_0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then I found that the group of units of S is
$$ S^*:=\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&c\end{pmatrix}:a,c\in \{ -1,1\},b\in \mathbb{Z} \Bigg\}$$

I want to show $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ 
has infinite order in S*.

Assume $$A^n=1,$$for some positive integer n

Consider $$A^{(n-1)}A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Since
 $$A^{(n-1)}\in S^*$$
so$$A^{(n-1)}A=\begin{pmatrix}a_k&0\\b_k&c_k\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then I obtain $$a_k=1,c_k=1,b_k+c_k=0 \Rightarrow b_k=-1$$

My issue here is what can I say about $$b_k=-1$$ would lead to a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply compute some powers of $A$, which suggest that
$$
A^n=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr n & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This can be quickly proved by induction. And clearly $A^n$ is never the unit matrix for $n\ge 1$.